# UIDatePicker EventValueChanged not showing actual Date/Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I have two UILabels

1: Time (Format: HH:MM)

2: Date (Format: MMMM dd, yyyy)

I have a UIDatePicker which is the UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime called: timeObjectReportedDatePicker

Each time the value of the datePicker changes, the two labels are supposed to show the respective value from the datePicker. So label 1 will show the HH:MM and label 2 will show the MMMM, dd, yyyy.

However this is not the case; rather for testing purposes I'm logging the value of the datePicker; which is only grabbing the current time/date. Regardless of the date that I change, or time; the value only changes to the actual date and time and not the picker value. Here is the code that I have in the header.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *timeObjectReportedDatePicker;

- (IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender;
```

Here is the code for the datePickerValueChanged method

```
-(void)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender{

   NSLog(@"datePicker Value Changed");
   NSDate *today1 = self.timeObjectReportedDatePicker.date;

   NSLog(@"PickerValue: %@",today1);
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
   NSString *dateString11 = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today1];
   dateObjectReportedUILabel.text=dateString11;
}
```

I do have the UIDatePicker SentEvent ValueChanged connected as an IBOutlet to the header file for the valueDidChange event.

Could someone shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You did not link timeObjectReportedDatePicker to the outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your action method as like

```
    - (IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender;
```

and execute the method as like

```
     -(void)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker*)sender{
     [self updateReportlabel: sender];

}

// for change the year and month
 -(void)updateReportlabel:(UIDatePicker*)sender{
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
  dateObjectReportedUILabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:sender.date];
      // call the update time method
      [self updateTimelabel: sender];

 }
 // for change the time 
-(void)updateTimelabel:(UIDatePicker*)sender{
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
  yourFirstLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:sender.date];

 }
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly! That makes sense. I appreciate it.